# Appropriate way to declare child routes in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I got a **UsersModule** with the following routing:

```
export const UsersRoutingModule = RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: 'users', component: UsersComponent,
    children: [
      { path: ':id', component: DetailUserComponent },
      { path: 'add', component: AddUserComponent },
      { path: 'edit', component: EditUserComponent }
    ]
  }
]);
```

Problem is when I access to `/users/anything` it always displays the **DetailUserComponent**, so, using child routes, How do I have to declare the children routes for `users`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change routing

```
export const UsersRoutingModule = RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: 'users', component: UsersComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'add', component: AddUserComponent },
      { path: 'edit', component: EditUserComponent },
      { path: ':id', component: DetailUserComponent },
    ]
  }
]);
```

Because in your routing id doesnot have any limits so even **something** can become an id

Comment: Is there a  way to define a regex expression to match in order to specify the id?

Comment: @feniixx this is what i am looking right now :) because it would help

Comment: @feniixx http://blog.devcross.net/2016/03/25/angular-2-router-and-regular-expressions/ look here.

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat the link is dead. Here's from wayback machine http://web.archive.org/web/20180123062701/http://blog.devcross.net:80/2016/03/25/angular-2-router-and-regular-expressions/ .